# How do i rename my WordPress live theme folder

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-admin

[image: code screenshot]

How do i rename this folder name in WordPress folder in stylesheet

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just rename the theme folder and update same into your style.css 'Theme Name: YourThemeName'

Comment: Please note, that after you rename your folder, you will have to activate it from the WordPress themes section.

Answer (score 0):

modify your "style name" in style.css and rename the theme folder.

Finally regenerate permalinks in "settings" -> "permalinks" -> "save changes".

Let me know.

Thank you